# Software that apply LZ77 and LZW dictionary based compression algorithm

Tags: compression, lzw

Are there good applications (software) that perform dictionary based compression algorithm (LZ77 and LZW). And it is better if the application show: Compression ratio, Compression and decompression Time.
I want to apply the compression in the **text** file and see the changes of file’s content after compressing.

Thanks

Comment: I prefer Windows. Linux- Ubuntu is OK too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the most widespread compression/decompression library is [`zlib`](http://zlib.net/), which uses LZ77.  It **is** incredibly portable and runs on Linux and Windows.  It also has a license with very few restrictions.

Starting with Windows XP, Windows [supports LZ compression natively](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365224.aspx) (see related functions).